# Page number in the margin note

Tags: page-numbering, marginnote

I've seen some books that have the page number in the middle of the page, in the margin note; i think it make it easier to look for a particular (IMHO). Is there any chance to do this in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

The [`backgound` package](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/background/background.pdf) can achieve this.

## All page numbers on right margin

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
  color=black,angle=0,opacity=1,scale=1,
  position=current page.east,anchor=left,
  contents={\tikz\node[fill=gray!50,align=center,text width=5ex]{\thepage};}
}


\begin{document}
%\setcounter{page}{100} % uncomment to see effect of large page number
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

---

## Page numbers on different of sides

If you want page numbers to be placed at different sides for odd and even pages, then you can enlist the help of [`changepage` package](http://ctan.cms.math.ca/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/changepage/changepage.pdf):

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{background}

\newcommand\pnum{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \checkoddpage
    \ifoddpage
      \node[fill=gray!50,align=center,text width=5ex,anchor=west]at(current page.west){\thepage};
    \else
      \node[fill=gray!50,align=center,text width=5ex,anchor=east]at(current page.east){\thepage};
    \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\backgroundsetup{color=black,angle=0,opacity=1,scale=1,contents={\pnum}}


\begin{document}
%\setcounter{page}{100} % uncomment to see effect of large page number
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since `background` will load `tikz` automatically, I think there is no need to load the package `tikz` manually. :)

Comment: @Ch'enMeng: Thanks `:)` It was there because I didn't use `background` initially. Doesn't hurt to leave it there anyways, as long as OP sees your comment `;)`

Answer (score 3):

With `eso-pic`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example
\usepackage{ifoddpage}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \AtTextCenter{%    
    \checkoddpage
     \ifoddpage
       \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr.5\paperwidth-5mm\relax},0){\colorbox{gray}{\makebox[10mm][c]{\thepage}}}%
     \else
       \put(\LenToUnit{\dimexpr-.5\paperwidth-5mm\relax},0){\colorbox{gray}{\makebox[10mm][c]{\thepage}}}%
     \fi
}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\blinddocument % just for the example
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1000}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]